# Discrete double integral in MATLAB if I know function value at each point

Tags: matlab

How do I calculate double integral if I know values of the function to be integrated at each and every point in x,y domain (values are discrete) in MATLAB? I have all the data stored in a file in .csv format. Actually, I'm trying to find ECC for the MIMO antenna and I got the values of the radiated field and now I'm stuck here in the integration part. Please help.

Comment: `sum` ? an integral is just a sum. you can use the trapezoid method, or just read about discrete numerical integrals in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do you mean an integration over a 2-dim domain?

Your question is more of a numerical recipes question than a Matlab question in my opinion.  Do you know the grid spacing of the data set of field values you are integrating?  Just summing can lead to low precision results, you'll need to choose an integration procedure.

Did you try google?

MATLAB has a trapezoid integral function that can be nested to produce multiple integrals (I've used this before).  The link to its description is below.  There are explicit examples using function calls and data sets.  I suspect that what you need is on this page.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html